# Where to put output file?

Tags: arcpy, files, results

I ran a script that I got from exporting a model that I built in Model Builder in ArcCatalog 10.3.1 and made edits to it (using the generous help from people on here). I essentially put in for my buffer, feature class to feature class, and spatial join processes to print if they already exist and then the code to delete them.

After running the script, I received this text in blue (I didn't play around with the color defaults on Python IDLE):

```
F:\Projects\Working\ModelProject\ModelData.gdb\Hurricanes_in_Counties_Feature_Class already exists!!
F:\Projects\Working\ModelProject\ModelData.gdb\Hurricanes_Buffer already exists!!
F:\Projects\Working\ModelProject\ModelData.gdb\Hurricanes_Counties_SpaJoi already exists!!
```

I was told that I need to put in the output files. My question is how do I even begin with an output file?

Here is my code for the buffer process:

```
import arcpy 
Hurricanes_Buffer = "F:\\Projects\\Working\\ModelProject\\ModelData.gdb\\Hurricanes_Buffer"
if arcpy.Exists(Hurricanes_Buffer):
    print "{} already exists!!".format(Hurricanes_Buffer)
    arcpy.Delete_management(Hurricanes_Buffer)

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(Hurricanes_in_Counties, Hurricanes_Buffer, v15_Miles, "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "", "PLANAR")
```

Comment: As per the [tour], please only write one question per question

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the snippet of code you are stuck with, and format it by selecting the code and pressing the `{ }` button

Comment: I think I fixed it to what you want. Sorry again.

Comment: I'm voting to close as this doesn't have enough info and is also too broad asking multiple questions.  @PolyGeo and myself (and probably others) have spent a fair bit of time over the past few days with helping you with how to write a question in order to get good answers but you don't appear to be taking much advice.  See [Writing code snippets to get quicker answers](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/4313/64785)

Comment: I changed it to single question as per your request.

Comment: see my comment about about selecting your code snippet and pressing the **{ }** button to format as code (rather than using the ` to surround your snippet)

Comment: I have pressed the button to enter in my code. Perhaps, I'm not doing it correctly. Let me try again.

Comment: I think I got it. Hopefully.

Comment: OK looks much better thanks.  Are you wanting to run this on one specified file at a time, or loop through a list or folder of files?  These two options will require different code

Comment: @Midavalo, thank you. As for what I want to do to run this one specified file at a time. My buffer data needs to go into my Spatial Join which should be the end result of my script.

Comment: You will want a loop if you want to run your script on multiple files one after the other.  IF you just want to specify a file and have your script run a number of different tasks on that one input file, then you may need something slightly different.

Comment: Those three printed lines cannot be coming from running just the code snippet that you have presented.

Comment: @Midavalo Yes. A loop is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

arcpy normally doesn't overwrite existing files, so if you get this message there is a problem somewhere: you tried to write a file and this file already exist. If you where in a loop, make sure that the name of the output files is modified at each iteration.

Comment: Please add your code snippet (edit your question) if you need more specific help. It is not possible to guess exactly what you are doing in this case. If you tried to run it and don't have a loop, then change the names of your files in arccatalog so that new files are not conflicting

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still confused. Do I need to create new files for those processes to put their output into?

Comment: no, most tools create an output file  and those file must not already exist

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better served by:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.overwriteOutput = True
```

Than delete

http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00210000000q000000

Overwrite tool output section explains why

Comment: Just be careful when turning on Overwrite that you don't inadvertently overwrite stuff you want to keep, like the last instance of running a tool for 40 hours.